# Remove data from the list in android

Tags: java, android

Hello every one i have a listview of array data of checkboxes which the user will select as the hobbies below is preview

[image]

and the hobbies will be shown upside but i am stuck of removing the hobbies by clicking it on up side and also when i select the 2 hobies then in show list it shows 2 times

bellow is the preview

[image]

also if i select the 3rd hobby then it show 3 times so please fix this for me and also if i uncheck the box it should remove from the view list also if i click on any hobby in the show list it still remove and uncheck automatically and if i click on save button all the hobbies should be selected

please fix this for me bellow is my code

```
Hobbies_Hobbies_List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (!Hobbies_Hobbies_List.isItemChecked(i))
                {
                    Hobbies_Hobbies_List.setItemChecked(i,false);
                }
                else
                {
                    Object object = Hobbies_Hobbies_List.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    String Hobby = String.valueOf(object);

                    for (int j=0;j<Hobbies_Hobbies_List.getCount();j++)
                    {
                        if (Hobbies_Hobbies_List.isItemChecked(j))
                        {
                            TextView text = new TextView(HobbiesActivity.this);
                            text.setText(Hobby+" ");
                            text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            Hobbies_Show.addView(text);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });


hobbies_save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have an adapter.
In an adapter you can modify your list (add or remove item, change text, color etc)

If you want to make your own list you will have to make your own adapter for your list. You can remove items in the adapter.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

    TextView textView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    CheckBox checkBox = rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    textView.setText(dataSet.get(position).myText);
    checkBox.setChecked(dataSet.get(position).myBool);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            // You can remove item here
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

For this you need your own data type.

Here a project with an example:
https://github.com/Asuki/SimpleListView

You also have to add the remove items to the other one list (maybe from the adapter)